# Issues compiling a patched version of pulseaudio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, compiling, gcc, make

I've been trying to compile [this version of Pulseaudio that has a patch](https://github.com/dmitryvk/pulseaudio/archive/12b13c75d3a9b377e0f7de7c86116e3af41ce5ee.tar.gz) but when I run

```
./configure
```

I get this output

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether UID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
configure: error: git-version-gen failed
`
```

Here is the output of automake

```
`configure.ac:89: warning: AC_COMPILE_IFELSE was called before AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS
../../lib/autoconf/specific.m4:368: AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS is expanded from...
configure.ac:89: the top level
configure.ac:106: warning: The 'AM_PROG_MKDIR_P' macro is deprecated, and its use is discouraged.
configure.ac:106: You should use the Autoconf-provided 'AC_PROG_MKDIR_P' macro instead,
configure.ac:106: and use '$(MKDIR_P)' instead of '$(mkdir_p)'in your Makefile.am files.
```

And here is the output of autoconf

```
configure.ac:89: warning: AC_COMPILE_IFELSE was called before AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS
../../lib/autoconf/specific.m4:368: AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS is expanded from...
configure.ac:89: the top level
```

What should I do? I have scoured the internet and I can't find a single thing about this problem.

Comment: Why don't you build according to the README with autogen?

Comment: using auto gen doesn't work, it gives me ./git-version-gen: Failed to determine git revision

Comment: Do you have `git` installed? I suggest installing `git` and cloning instead of downloading `tar.gz`. It builds for me.

Comment: Using the git clone may be your best bet. For this source  the tar.gz chould have had a file `.tarball-version` which would have prevented this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use git cloning instead of downloading a tar.

Run

```
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/dmitryvk/pulseaudio.git
cd pulseaudio
```

You need some libs too

```
sudo apt-get install libjson0 libjson0-dev libsndfile1-dev
./autogen.sh
CFLAGS="-ggdb3 -O0" LDFLAGS="-ggdb3" ./configure --without-caps
make
```

And it builds OK.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think to try that! Thank you so much,  I have been trying to get this to build for so long. Also if anybody's curious the patch says it fixes issues with PulseAudio going out of sync when the signal drops for a second on Bluetooth equipment, so if anybody is having that issue they might want to try this.